# Log messages from inside Framework to XCode Console

Tags: swift, xcode, logging, xcode8, kitura

I have a XCode project which builds an executable (`swift package init --type executable && swift package generate-xcodeproj`). The executable imports a framework which normally logs messages to the console, but because the framework is imported by the executable the log messages are not shown.

How can I display log messages (`Log.debug("Bla bla")`) from inside a module/framework invoked by an executable in the XCode console?

Comment: Did you have any success in this question? I'm facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

As [this thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-do-you-print-output-from-package-swift-execution/34360/2) mentioned:

> It isn’t designed for that sort of thing, because once the package is
> a dependency, it might be loaded multiple times for different versions
> while the dependency graph is being resolved—even multiple times at
> once.
>
> If you are trying to debug something, swift package has subcommands
> like describe, dump‐package and show-dependencies. swift package
> --help will show you the complete list of available commands.